# Django model self doesn't count as instance?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to resolve a `ValueError: Cannot query "X": Must be "Y" instance.` issue. The problem is, my `X` definitely seems to be a `Y` instance. In my case, `X` is `self` within a `UserAccount` model. Here are some code snippets:

```py
from other.thing import do_something

class UserAccount(...):  # eventually subclasses from Django's user model
    @property
    def is_weekly_email_enabled(self):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # Debugging entrypoint
        return do_something(self)

class UserPreference(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)  # This points to UserAccount
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# In other/thing.py :
def do_something(user):
    return UserPreference.objects.get(user=user, name="some_preference")
```

I've set a `pdb` breakpoint in `is_weekly_email_enabled()` to confirm things.
Actual exception with testing output:

```py
ValueError: Cannot query "user1": Must be "UserAccount" instance.
(Pdb) self
<UserAccount: user1>
(Pdb) type(self)
<class 'accounts.models.UserAccount'>
(Pdb) isinstance(self, UserAccount)
True
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Try changing to `return do_something(self.instance)`, at the end of your `is_weekly_email_enabled` function

Comment: Are there maybe two `UserAccount` classes in different locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, there is nothing wrong with the way I'm using the models and utility function. I had a circular dependency (my `models.py` was importing `do_something` and the file with `do_something` was importing the models) but it wasn't clear **due to my development process**:

I was using the Django shell and `importlib` to reimport modules as I made small tweaks to them. When restarting the shell and retrying everything from scratch, it was much clearer. I resorted to importing the models *in the utility function itself*, not in the file.

Comment: This one saved me, I just restarted the kernel in the notebook and I was good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `return do_something(self)` to `return do_something(self.user)`